# Extract Products From Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, text, extract

I am trying to extract only the products from the names column
below.  I am struggling to find what regex pattern would work for this, or maybe even a named entity recognition but this being all caps I don't think a complex nlp solution would be best for this.
If there is some regex pattern that could extract everything in between the date and the city that is my goal.  Example of ideal output is below:

```
# example of our dataframe
data = {'Names':['02/25 APPLE AIR PODS LOS ANGELES  CA', 
             '01/31 AMAZON PRIME VIDEO MIAMI FL', 
             '05/14 SAMSUNG TV NASHVILLE TN']} 

# Convert Dictionary to Dataframe  
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

df output expected
names:
APPLE AIR PODS
AMAZON PRIME VIDEO
SAMSUNG TV
```

Comment: That is hard, you need find the name of city , then remove it

Comment: @BEN_YO only problem is my real dataset has an infinite number of cities... so I'm trying to find some sort of pattern.  If I knew all the cities I could put that in a list and remove it but unfortunately any city is possible for this...

Comment: The obvious strategy is to have a list of cities and see if they're part of your column=Names (get index and you're dome) . Your tools with pandas will not do it if your list is huge.

Comment: @adhg maybe pyspark if a big list?

Comment: 1. Are all dates of xx/xx format?
2. Do you have a list of cities with 2 or more words in their name (like LOS ANGELES)?
If yes, you can easily split the text, and remove date and last 2 words (or 3 if the city name has 2 words) tha trepresent the city and the state

Comment: @archer makes since!  All dates are that format.   Do you have a code example for this?

Comment: I added an answer. However you need some list of cities with 2 or more words, as there is no other way for computer to understand if a word belongs to a city name or not

Comment: @archer could you add the example with the list of cities I have above?  I am trying to connect your indexing with how you incorporate the list of cities... list_of_cities = ['LOS ANGELES','MIAMI','NASHVILLE']

Comment: Added some code so that it will work with 2words cities. Don;t forget to fill the list with all 2word cities.
In case you don't need al that explanations, let me know so that i will clear my answer to keep only the final code

Answer (score 1):

The following removes the date, the state and one word of the city.

```
l=data['Names']
l=[i.replace('  ', ' ') for i in l] #there are some double spaces
m=[' '.join(i.split(' ')[1:-2]) for i in l]
print(m)
```

Output:

```
['APPLE AIR PODS LOS', 'AMAZON PRIME VIDEO', 'SAMSUNG TV']
```

If you want it in a dataframe format:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Names':m})
print(df)

                Names
0  APPLE AIR PODS LOS
1  AMAZON PRIME VIDEO
2          SAMSUNG TV
```

When the city name has 2 words the last word of the result will be the first word of some city and must be removed. We must have a list to check for it. For example if your cities are `cities=['SAN FRANSISCO', 'LOS ANGELES', 'NEW YORK', 'NASHVILLE', 'MIAMI']` you can create a new list with first words of 2word-length cities and make the comparison, like below:

```
two_words=[i for i in cities if len(i.split(' '))>1]
first_of_two_words=[i.split(' ')[0] for i in two_words]
```

#result of this will be
And finally you can check for the last word of your m list and remove if it is in first_of_two_words:

```
for i in range(len(m)):
    if i.split(' ')[-1] in first_of_two_words:
        m=[' '.join(i.split(' ')[-1]) for i in m]
```

**Final Code:**

```
l=data['Names']
cities=['SAN FRANSISCO', 'LOS ANGELES', 'NEW YORK', 'NASHVILLE', 'MIAMI']
two_words=[i for i in cities if len(i.split(' '))>1]
first_of_two_words=[i.split(' ')[0] for i in two_words]
l=[i.replace('  ', ' ') for i in l] #there are some double spaces
m=[' '.join(i.split(' ')[1:-2]) for i in l]
for i in range(len(m)):
    if m[i].split(' ')[-1] in first_of_two_words:
        m[i]=' '.join(m[i].split(' ')[:-1])
df=pd.DataFrame({'Names':m})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                Names
0      APPLE AIR PODS
1  AMAZON PRIME VIDEO
2          SAMSUNG TV
```